# Android onPressBack Issue

Tags: android

Here the issue is if user open one menu and press back then, user getting my home page, where if user open one menu,followed by if user open second menu and press back instead of getting my home page the app is getting exit. How to solve this problem?

```
 public void onBackPressed() {
    MaterialSearchView searchView = (MaterialSearchView) 
    findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    if (searchView.isOpen()) {
        // Close the search on the back button press.
        searchView.closeSearch();
    } else {
        if(count == 0) {
            count++;
            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame
                    , new Main2Activity()).addToBackStack("tag").commit();
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            try {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Welcome " +
                        dashboardObject.getJSONObject("studentDTO").getJSONObject("student").get("name").toString());
                notifications1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                home.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                search1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                setActionBarBackground(R.color.nav_home);
                getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
                toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.background_color));
                toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_black3);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else {
            finish();
            count--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you done fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); in your activity

Comment: You can go through with this link also http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/10/01/handling-back-button-press-inside-fragments/

Comment: You have called finish(); and it will close the activity.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved just we have to declare count=0 to the menu from where u can use onPressedBack